# In VS2012 is there a keyboard shortcut to give focus to the code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS2012 is there a keyboard shortcut to give focus to the code editor?

CTRL+TAB works most of the time, but on those occasions when the code editor already has focus but you didn't notice then this will switch windows instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think **ALT+0** is what you're finding.